# not able to print the table header in pdf

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pdf

I have generated html table in response and I have used auto table to generate pdf .
I want to print the thead as table header but now first row of tbody is consider as header.What I did wrong.How to get the thead as table header. https://jsfiddle.net/2s3ro1tq/3/ Please check my fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt use a `tr` in you header, if you use the same logic as for your body it will look like this

```
$('#geo_summary thead').append(
  $('<tr>').append(Object.keys(geodata[0]).map(x => $('<td>').text(x)))
);
          
$('#geo_summary tbody').append(
  geodata.map(row => $('<tr>').append(
    Object.values(row).map(x => $('<td>').text(x))
  ))
);
```

Then it should generate correctly